# How to extract bit fields from a hex value string in Tcl and output them as integers?

Tags: tcl

I have strings representing hex values which contain multiple fields of varying bit length. I must extract them and print them on the screen. e.g 0x17AF018D1 is a 33 bit hex value where the bits are indexed 0 to 32; I need to exctract the numbers that are contained in bits 0-5, 6-7, 8-21, 22-30, 31-32.

There are multiple ways to go about doing this I am sure. What would be the best method to achieve this feet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hex value can be treated directly as an integer. Tcl's integers are actually arbitrary precision values, but are optimised to work efficiently with the host system's machine word size. (Tcl transparently handles the details for you.)

This means that a bit field extractor can be just like this (assuming little endian):

```
proc BitField {value from to} {
    if {$from > $to} {
        error "reversed bit field description"
    }
    # How many bits wide is the field?
    set width [expr {$to - $from + 1}]
    # Convert the width into a bit mask in the lowest bits
    set mask [expr {(1 << $width) - 1}]
    # Shift and mask the value to get the field
    expr {($value >> $from) & $mask}
}

set abc 0x17AF018D1
puts [BitField $abc 0 5]
puts [BitField $abc 6 7]
puts [BitField $abc 8 21]
puts [BitField $abc 22 30]
# You are aware this overlaps?
puts [BitField $abc 30 32]
```

For *non-overlapping contiguous* fields, you can do this instead:

```
# Note that this is big endian as it is working with the string representation
scan [format "%033lb" $abc] "%3b%8b%14b%2b%6b" e d c b a

puts $a
puts $b
puts $c
puts $d
puts $e
```

The values in the strings are the overall value/field widths: `%033lb` means format as a 33 digit binary value (`101111010111100000001100011010001` in your example), and `%3b` means parse a 3 digit binary value at this point. (Unfortunately, we can't make that much more readable as there must not be spaces between the `scan` specifiers as there's no spaces in the input data we've just generated.)

Comment: Overlapping fields can be handled, but need extra steps with `string range` to do the field extraction. The steps with shifting and masking are how C compilers do bit field extraction.

Comment: I have made correction so there is no overlap anymore

Comment: There is one more point, what if the value I have extracted is a signed value? Is there a method to convert it to signed value automatically? I could write a function to do this as well which will take the value and the bit length of it and then do arithmetic to convert it to the signed representation. In this way, the 3 bit value 7 shall be converted into -1.